# How to get rid of the extensions in Stata loop?

Tags: loops, csv, stata

I'm using Stata to analyze data from `.csv` files. I wrote a loop to go through all the files in a directory, so that I can `insheet` them once and for all. Here it is:

```
cd "C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Tweet Archivist\csv2806"
! dir *.csv /a-d /b > filelist.txt

* Looping through the filelist to transform all of them in .dta files
file open trial4 using "C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Tweet Archivist\csv2806\filelist.txt", read
file read trial4 line
while r(eof)==0 {
  cd "C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Tweet Archivist\csv2806"
  insheet using `line', tab
  save `line'.dta, replace
  drop _all
  file read trial4 line
  }
file close trial4
```

My problem is this: when I use this method the `.csv` file extension gets incorporated in the filename in Stata so that I have `file1.csv.dta`. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I know it might seem a trivial question and even a rather inane one since I might just open the file and manually eliminate the `.csv`, but I would like to know if there's a way to do it all in Stata. I tried the `rename` command in DOS but that eliminates the extension and then Stata doesn't recognize the files as `.csv`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is just some macro manipulation documented at `help extended_fcn`.

At the same time I want to recommend a much simpler approach in which you use Stata to get the list of files. (It's explicit in your code that you are using Windows, but the approach here is cross-platform.) Here it is:

```
cd "C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Tweet Archivist\csv2806"
fs *.csv 

foreach f in `r(files)' { 
    insheet using `f', tab clear 
    local F : subinstr local f ".csv" "" 
    save `F'.dta, replace
}
```

The user-written command `fs` here is a convenience wrapper around Stata's tools for getting filenames from the operating system. Use `ssc install fs` to install it.

The `fs` call can be more complicated, including two or more wildcarded file specifications. See the help for `fs` for details.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That approach is much easier. I'm reading now the extended help and working out how to solve my problem. Also, as a student who has been using Stata for a bit, I want to thank you for all the time you've unknowingly solved my problems with your help here and on Statalist. Your answers are always very appreciated.